# DataCombo not getting refresh after returning to Form

Tags: sql-server, data-binding, vb6, adodb

I have this very very old VB6 WinForms application. It has a very simple initial window that shows a combo box with some data retrieved from a MS SQL Server, by using ADODB 2.8. It has a checkbox to define how to filter retrieved data from the server.

The content of the combobox is being correctly added when the form is loaded. Still, I have a button that shows a new window with data related to the selected item in the combobox. Once I close that other window, I reopen the original window and the combobox is empty, even if the **Form_Load** method is executed and, therefore, **Check1_Click** method also is executed. Howhever, if I clicked on the checkbox, the **Check1_Click** event is triggered and executed OK and the combobox is filled.

When the window is loaded the first time, the **Form_Load** is executed and the combo is filled correctly. Everytime **Check1_Click**, the recordset contains the correct information, it is just that when returning to the window, it just wont show it on the combobox.

Are there any steps I should take to refresh the content of the combobox once the window is reopened?

The Combobox is of type ***MSDataListLib.DataCombo***

The click method is something like this.

```
Private Sub Check1_Click()
    Dim SQL As String

    'If checked'
    If Me.Check1.Value = 1 Then
        SQL = "SELECT TABLE1.NAME, TABLE1.LASTNAME, TABLE1.NAME + TABLE1.LASTNAME AS FULLNAME " & _ 
              " WHERE TABLE1.ACTIF = 'Y' ORDER BY TABLE1.NAME, TABLE1.LASTNAME"
    'If not checked'
    Else
        SQL = "SELECT TABLE1.NAME, TABLE1.LASTNAME, TABLE1.NAME + TABLE1.LASTNAME AS FULLNAME " & _ 
              " ORDER BY TABLE1.NAME, TABLE1.LASTNAME"
    End If

    Disconnect
    Set Cn = Connect
    Set objRec = CloseRecordSet(objRec)
    Set objRec = New ADODB.Recordset
    With objRec
        .CursorLocation = adUseServer
        .Open SQL, Cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    End With
    With Me.FullName
        Set .RowSource = objRec
        .ListField = "FULLNAME"
        .DataField = "FULLNAME"
    End With
    Me.FullName.Refresh
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

This is the implementation of the rest of the methods

```
'Connexion ADODB'
Public adoDbConn As ADODB.Connection


Private Sub Form_Load()
    Check1_Click
    Me.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Set objRec = CloseRecordSet(objRec)
    Disconnect
    Set Cn = Nothing

    With Me.FullName
        Set .RowSource = Nothing
        .ListField = ""
        .DataField = ""
    End With
    Me.FullName.Refresh
    Me.Refresh
End Sub 


Sub Disconnect()
    If Not adoDbConn Is Nothing Then
        If adoDbConn.State = adStateOpen Then adoDbConn.Close
    End If
    Set adoDbConn = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function Connect() As ADODB.Connection
    If adoDbConn Is Nothing Then        
        Set adoDbConn = New ADODB.Connection        
        ' Specify the OLE DB provider.'
        adoDbConn.Provider = "sqloledb"
        adoDbConn.Mode = adModeReadWrite
        ' Specify connection string on Open method.'
        adoDbConn.Open ChaineConnexion      
    End If      
    Set Connect = adoDbConn     
End Function

Public Function CloseRecordSet(rs As ADODB.Recordset) As Object
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
    End If
    Set CloseRecordSet = Nothing
End Function
```

### UPDATE

Method that loads the detail window

```
    'Showing the Detail Window'
Private Sub OpenFormDetail_Click()

    'If none is selected'
    If Me.FullName = "" Then
        'Show warning'
        Ret = MsgBox("Select one element!", vbExclamation, "ATTENTION !")
        Me.FullName.SetFocus
    Else

        'Storing fullname to use in detail other window'
        Globale.FullName = Right(Me.FullName, 11)

        'Load Detail Window'
        Load frmDetailWindow
        frmDetailWindow.Show

        'Unloads this window'
        Unload Me

    End If
End Sub
```

Method in Detail Window that closes it and reopens the original window

```
    'Showing the original Window'
Private Sub Return_Click()

    'Open initial window'
    Load frmInitialWindow
    frmInitialWindow.Show

    'Closes Detail Window'
    Unload frmDetailWindow

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show the code for "a button that shows a new window". Are you unloading the first form? How do you "reopen the original window" - please show the code for that.

Comment: Why would you do a me.Refresh in the Form_Unload event?

Comment: I added the code for opening the child window and returning to the original window. The forms are always being unloaded.